# Paragraph field titles showing even when set to visually hidden

Tags: 8, entities, paragraphs

I am using the following code to render a paragraph entity in a twig template: `{{ content.entity_name}}`

A second template renders the paragraph's fields correctly using:

```
<h2>{{ content.nav_title }}</h2>
```

The problem is it showing the label even when set to "visually hidden" and when set to label "hidden" it doesn't display the content at all.

[image: Display settings]

For example, it should render:

```
<h2>Example Option Two</h2>
<h2>Example Option Two</h2>
```

But when set to label "visually hidden" instead it renders (with extra spaces):

```
Entity Name Label



<h2>Example Option Two</h2>
<h2>Example Option Two</h2>
```

Finally, when set to label: "hidden" it renders (correct number of items but no content or markup from template):

```
{ item.content }}
{ item.content }}
```

Comment: You are missing a brace here, it should be `{{ item.content }}`.

Comment: It looks like you have the _field_ label set to "Hidden". So, this means the label won't show up in the "field.html.twig" template level. It seems the the "Entity Name Label" is coming from some parent template. I'd recommend turning on twig debugging. (in services.yml set twig.config debug: true ). Then when viewing you web source in your browser you will be able to identify exactly where the unwanted text is coming from. (or you can at least include that info in your question).

Comment: @kevin that is the rendered content not my code that missing a brace.